# Dynamically populated Django field does not display choices

Tags: python, django

I want to dynamically populate a Django ChoiceField from a stored procedure. However, I cannot get the results to display in the Django admin. It comes up blank. What am I missing? Sorry if I've asked a question that's already been answered. I've already looked and looked...

```
class Plot(models.Model):
    plot_claim_type = models.CharField('Plot Claim Type', max_length=7)

class PlotAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlotAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        c = connection.cursor()
        try:
            c.execute("BEGIN")
            c.callproc("udf_getcodetypes", "1")
            results = c.fetchall()
            for o in results:
                self.base_fields['plot_claim_type'].choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(o[0], str(o[1])))
        finally:
            c.close()

@admin.register(Plot)

class PlotAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PlotAdminForm
```

Comment: You can't assign a `MultipleChoiceField` to `choices`. You just want to assign it to `self.fields['plot_claim_type']`. But your loop is wrong as well, since you just assigning the last `o`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop through the results is assigning and reassigning so you end up with just one assignment (the last `o` in `results`). And you can't assign a `Field` type to `choices`, that doesn't make sense.

Just try this (instead of `for o in results` loop):

```
results = c.fetchall()
self.fields['plot_claim_type'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(
    (o[0], str(o[1])) for o in results))
```